# Heroku change github repository

Tags: heroku, github

I have a fully working application with data persisted in the database but I need to change the github repository associated with it.
So I have something like:

```
https://github.com/foo/bar
```

And I need to change to:

```
https://github.com/bar/foo
```

Without doing anything to the application hosted and without losing data.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, Heroku doesn't know (or care) what your GitHub repository is called. You don't even need a GitHub repository to use Heroku. Don't you push to it from a local copy?

Comment: I have a local folder called A, which is hosted at github as github.com/A, what I need to do is change heroku to read from my folder B, which is hosted at github as github.com/B

Comment: Well, Heroku doesn't "read from" local folders. Nothing at Heroku will change until you push to it, or change settings. Do `A` and `B` share history?

Comment: A and B are the same. I simply had to change the repository from a personal to a organisation.

Comment: So just deploy your next version from `B`. Heroku doesn't know what machine or directory you pushed from.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Heroku's Github integration (where Heroku either automatically deploys a specific Github branch or you can choose a branch to deploy manually) you can disconnect your old repository and connect the new one. Navigate to `Deploys` tab, and click the `Disconnect...` button in `App connected to Github` section:

[image: Disconnect button]

Then connect your new repository as you did initially.

Note that if your repository was transferred to another account / organization you may need to grant Heroku permissions to access that. When you do so and reconnect the repository you may find two Heroku webhooks installed, under `Settings / Webhooks` on Github. One of those will be shown as failing - just remove the one that fails.